# Twitter Bootstrap Setting Input text fluid size won't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

Here is my site's body: (With twitter bootstrap 2.0)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid" style="text-align: center">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <form class="well form-search">
        <input type="text" class="span7 input-large search-query" />
        <button type="submit" class="span3 btn btn-primary" >Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the text and the submit button to be centered and be fluid 7:3, but when I set the span class to them they break to a new line, the text on the first line and the input submit on the other line.
What could/should I do in order to make them be on the same horizontal line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** [version 2.1.0](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/v2.1.0) has been released, so you should check the offset solution below, as it is provided by default in this version (and probably future ones)

---

It appears that bootstrap does not make input span float : [github forms.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.0.4/less/forms.less#L245)

So here is what you could use :

```css
.form-span input[type="text"][class*="span"] { float: left; }
```

#### Edit

For fluidity, you need to use a `.container-fluid` because `.container` has a fixed size (which makes fixed the fluid grid inside).

For the centering, I see 2 solutions:

Using inline text centering : (definitely not the best choice)

```
.inline-center { text-align: center!important; }
.inline-center [class*="span"] { float: none!important; display: inline-block!important; }
```

Or you can use the fluid `.offsetX` classes, which will be available [very soon](https://twitter.com/twbootstrap/status/232936019366916096) in the [version 2.1](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/e2336ef02ab620277e2d81f3fc6b4ff69e027ae4/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css#L392) or [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/3230479)

```html
<input type="text" class="offset1 span7 input-large search-query" />
<button type="submit" class="span3 btn btn-primary" >Search</button>
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/NEmXL/4/)

Comment: It works, but the inputs are moved to the side, (they aren't centered), and they are not responding fluidly to re-sizing.

Comment: @agam360 sorry, missed it. Check my edit, and you should choose the offset option.